# Is there a way to disable validations on ADF page when clicking on a <af:button>?

Tags: jsf-2, oracle12c, oracle-adf

I have tried setting the required attribute as follows in my input text:
required="#{ param['form:save'] == null}"
but the validation for required attribute are still being run .

I saw a few blogs where f:params are being used but the same cannot be set on the af:button. What other approach can be used here?

My save button code is:

```html
<af:button actionListener="#{invokeActionBean.setAction}" id="save" textAndAccessKey="Save" styleClass="secondary-button" action="#{invokeActionBean.action}" partialSubmit="false" rendered="#{actionAvailable.updateAvailable}">
  <f:attribute name="ACTION_MENU_ITEM" value="bindings.update" />
</af:button>
```

Comment: Most likely the same way as with a normal jsf button. Investigate that

Comment: I did investigate and somehow it did not work and hence the question. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: From the question it is not clear you investigated. See [ask]. And thank you for replying more than a week after the comment and the answer...

Answer (score 3):

You set the immediate property of the button to true.

```
<af:button ... immediate="true"/>
```

Comment: So i should add immediate="true" on the save button and all the input fields that i don't want to be validated. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: I tried adding immediate= "true" on the button above. This lead to error :from RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1.  I also added immediate="true" on the mandatory field. Then it shows required error when i try  to save as well as submit